# Matplotlib: Finding out xlim and ylim after zoom

Tags: python, matplotlib

you for sure know a fast way how I can track down the limits of my figure after having zoomed in? I would like to know the coordinates precisely so I can reproduce the figure with `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim`.
I am using the standard qt4agg backend.

edit: I know I can use the cursor to find out the two positions in the lower and upper corner, but maybe there is formal way to do that?

Comment: You can use `ax.get_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim` to retrieve the limits.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

matplotlib has an event handling API you can use to hook in to actions like the ones you're referring to. The [Event Handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) page gives an overview of the events API, and there's a (very) brief mention of the x- and y- limits events on the [Axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) page.

> The `Axes` instance supports callbacks through a callbacks attribute which is a `CallbackRegistry` instance. The events you can connect to are `xlim_changed` and `ylim_changed` and the callback will be called with `func(ax)` where `ax` is the `Axes` instance.

In your scenario, you'd want to register callback functions on the `Axes` object's `xlim_changed` and `ylim_changed` events. These functions will get called whenever the user zooms or shifts the viewport.

Here's a minimum working example:

**Python 2**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#
# Some toy data
x_seq = [x / 100.0 for x in xrange(1, 100)]
y_seq = [x**2 for x in x_seq]

#
# Scatter plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(x_seq, y_seq)

#
# Declare and register callbacks
def on_xlims_change(event_ax):
    print "updated xlims: ", event_ax.get_xlim()

def on_ylims_change(event_ax):
    print "updated ylims: ", event_ax.get_ylim()

ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', on_xlims_change)
ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', on_ylims_change)

#
# Show
plt.show()
```

---

**Python 3**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#
# Some toy data
x_seq = [x / 100.0 for x in range(1, 100)]
y_seq = [x**2 for x in x_seq]

#
# Scatter plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(x_seq, y_seq)

#
# Declare and register callbacks
def on_xlims_change(event_ax):
    print("updated xlims: ", event_ax.get_xlim())

def on_ylims_change(event_ax):
    print("updated ylims: ", event_ax.get_ylim())

ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', on_xlims_change)
ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', on_ylims_change)

#
# Show
plt.show()
```

Comment: This example is not working for Python 3. Even if `print`s and `xrange` are corrected, `axes.get_xlim()` does not produce values.

Comment: @eatcrayons That is correct, because `axes` is not defined; it needs to be `ax.get_xlim()` - I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
print ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()
```

Comment: This is probably not what OP was asking about; in my experience these functions return the limits given by set_xlim(), but are oblivious to what view the user has manually panned/zoomed afterwards.

Comment: Then why does the accepted answer work? It also uses `.get_xlim`.

Comment: Yes this answer is correct in the sense that `ax.get_xlim()` will return the current limits of the plot at any point in time, even after zooming. So if one is able to interact with the figure and call such command interactively, e.g. in an IPython session, this works fine. If the plot is produced by a script, you usually do not have this option; in that case the other answer shows how to use the events needed to be able to print the limits.