# How to enforce both xlim and ylim while using ax.axis('equal')?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I want to use `ax.axis('equal')` to force even spacing on X & Y, but I also want to prescribe specific ranges for the X and Y axes. If the margins are also fixed, the problem is over constrained and the result is shown on the left side of the Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv0mX.png). If instead, the margins were allowed to automatically increase themselves to take up the slack, then `xlim` and `ylim` could stay as I set them while still satisfying `axis('equal')`. An example of what I'm after is shown on the right side of Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv0mX.png). **How can I allow the plot margins to "float"?**

```
f,ax=plt.subplots(1) #open a figure
ax.axis('equal') #make the axes have equal spacing
ax.plot([0,20],[0,20]) #test data set

#change the plot axis limits
ax.set_xlim([2,18]) 
ax.set_ylim([5,15])

#read the plot axis limits
xlim2=array(ax.get_xlim())
ylim2=array(ax.get_ylim())

#define indices for drawing a rectangle with xlim2, ylim2
sqx=array([0,1,1,0,0])
sqy=array([0,0,1,1,0])

#plot a thick rectangle marking the xlim2, ylim2
ax.plot(xlim2[sqx],ylim2[sqy],lw=3) #this does not go all the way around the edge
```

[image: actual and desired output]
Figure 1: output from the above code snippet.

Comment: You should put `set_xlim`, `set_ylim` to the end to avoid the automatic rescaling.

Comment: @dnalow It doesn't work if I delete everything after `ax.set_ylim()`, and it doesn't work if I copy `set_xlim()`, `set_ylim()` to the end after everything else is done.

Comment: this is because of `ax.axis('equal'). It fixes the stepping, so the subplotsize has to fit  your limits which means, in turn, that your figure size has to match  or the subplot parameters

Comment: Unless the margins resize themselves automatically, which is what I'm asking for.

Comment: Interesting and related: The `tight=True` keyword in `autoscale()` sets `xlim` or `ylim` so the plot box hugs the data. `plt.autoscale(enable=True,axis='both',tight=True)`

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730467/how-can-i-get-the-actual-axis-limits-when-using-ax-axisequal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ax.set_aspect('equal',adjustable='box')
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it had to be this easy.

Comment: By the way, this can replace `ax.axis('equal')` in the original question.

Comment: `adjustable='box-forced'` may be preferable, especially when sharing axes. See http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me on matplotlib version '3.5.1'. I get this error: NotImplementedError: Axes3D currently only supports the aspect argument 'auto'. You passed in 'equal'.

Comment: This solution was only tested for 2D axes, not 3D.