# Is there a function to draw a horizontal ray on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a horizontal ray instead of horizontal line. Matplotlib has axhline() function. But it starts drawing from at the beginning of the chart. I am setting points at the high and low of the bar as you can see in the attached picture.

Is there a way to draw a line on a specific point?

I have tried `fillstyle="right"` but i think this is not something i am looking for.

[image: Horizontal ray]

Comment: use xmin and xmax as fraction of the plot you want to cover. matplotlib.pyplot.axhline(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=1, hold=None, **kwargs)[source]

Comment: This doesn't work. In this case the price is 1.168

Comment: suppose your total xrange is 4, then your xmin=1.168/4

Comment: My xrange is 70. y is 1.168 and the point is at 59

Comment: try axhline(y=1.168, xmin=59/70)

Comment: Ah ok. I have tried this after your comment. However there are still deviations. The line does not start from exact point

Comment: To work with data coordinates (not axes coordinates), use `plt.hlines`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, one can draw horizontal rays using `plt.axhline`. For example, the following code produces a box-plot with a horizontal ray:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mu, sigma = 50, 25

value1 = 1.5*mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value2 = mu + 1.5*sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value3 = 0.5*mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value4 = mu + 0.5*sigma*np.random.randn(100)

box_plot_data=[value1,value2,value3,value4]
plt.boxplot(box_plot_data)
plt.axhline(y=90, xmin=0.380, xmax=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: Boxplot with ray]

The data is random and the colors are default, but the idea is the same. The `xrange` on a default boxplot is `[0, 1]`, with separated into equally spaced regions for each box. Each box is centered in its region, so the four boxes are centered at 0.125, 0.375, .625, and 0.875.

To draw a horizonal line from the second boxplot to the right, one gives the `xmin` value to be approximately 0.375. I say approximately because matplotlib will slightly overextend based on the linewidth, so it's usually a good idea to add 0.005 (or a number depending on the linewidth you use in your axhline). This is why I actually used `xmin=0.380` instead of `xmin=0.375`.

Comment: Hi. My xrange is 70. y is 1.168 and the point is at 59. I don't know how you calculated these values.

Comment: @DonCoder If your point is at 59, and the range is 70, then you should start your xline at approximately 59/70. I typically expect (59/70 + 0.005) to account for the width of the line. If you give your actual code, it's easier to fill in the differences.

Answer (score -2):

I guess the easiest is to plot a line from `(n,y0)` to `(xend,y0)`, where `xend` is the coordinate of the right edge of the axes. One may find out e.g. via

```
xstart, xend = ax.get_xlim()
```

*after* having plotted the boxplot. `n` would be the boxplot number and `y0` the y coordinate where to plot the line (I suppose the latter is known?)
For `n=2` and `y0=90`, plotting the line is straight forward,

```
ax.plot([2,xend],[90,90])
```

Complete example (taking over the boxplot case from @davidlowryduda's answer):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 50, 25

value1 = 1.5*mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value2 = mu + 1.5*sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value3 = 0.5*mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value4 = mu + 0.5*sigma*np.random.randn(100)

box_plot_data=[value1,value2,value3,value4]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(box_plot_data)

xstart, xend = ax.get_xlim()
ax.plot([2,xend],[90,90])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The drawback of this is that the line will not be preseved upon zooming or panning. If that is required [a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490436/matplotlib-finding-out-xlim-and-ylim-after-zoom) needs to be used.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 50, 25

value1 = 1.5*mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value2 = mu + 1.5*sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value3 = 0.5*mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value4 = mu + 0.5*sigma*np.random.randn(100)

box_plot_data=[value1,value2,value3,value4]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(box_plot_data)

xstart, xend = ax.get_xlim()
line, = ax.plot([2,xend],[90,90])

def callback(evt):
    xstart, xend = ax.get_xlim()
    line.set_xdata((2,xend))

ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', callback)

plt.show()
```

With this, even after zooming or panning the line stays where it should be.

A different option is to enhance the `ConnectionPatch` to allow for arbitrary transformations, such that you can provide a transform which would take the `x` coordinate in terms of axes coordinates and the y coordinate in terms of data coordinates. This transform is given by the `ax.get_yaxis_transform()`. With the subclassed `ConnectionPatch` shown below this allows to achieve the same as above without the need of a callback.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

class EnhancedConnector(ConnectionPatch):
    def _get_xy(self, x, y, s, axes=None):
        p = super()._get_xy(x, y, s, axes=axes)
        if p is None:
            return s.transform_point((x, y))
        else:
            return p

mu, sigma = 50, 25

value1 = 1.5*mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value2 = mu + 1.5*sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value3 = 0.5*mu + sigma*np.random.randn(100)
value4 = mu + 0.5*sigma*np.random.randn(100)

box_plot_data=[value1,value2,value3,value4]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(box_plot_data)

transB = ax.get_yaxis_transform() 
p = EnhancedConnector(xyA=(2,90), xyB=(1,90), coordsA="data", coordsB=transB, 
                    axesA=ax, axesB=ax)
ax.add_patch(p)

plt.show()
```