# Matplotlib Query: Connecting max value to corresponding Y point

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

I have the plot above done out for a project I am currently working on. I am relatively new to matplotlib and want to ask would there be any way to connect the max point of each line to the y axis along the lines of something like this (except straight and not as poorly done :) ):
[image]

Comment: of course: you already have the last y values of every plotted line. And you get the minimum x value of the x axis via `plt.xlim()[0]` or `ax.get_xlim()[0]`.

Comment: Thanks that may be useful in the future to know

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536531/4124317), especially the last solution within on how to connect points defined in different coordinate systems with a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the following code allows me to draw these lines:

```
plt.axhline(y=0.8462, color='r', linestyle='--')
```

Which produces:

[image]

I can just repeat this for the other max values of y.

Comment: Exactly, nice solution. And with an additional kwarg `zorder=0` they'll all be in the background. (Or you plot them first of course)

Comment: Oh brilliant a background one is what I would like thanks for the assist

Comment: I tried both of those solutions man but they still appear in the forefront

Answer (score 1):

example addressing the foreground issue of the hlines mentioned in the comments here.

plots visualizing the discussed variants:

[image]

created with this code:

```
data = [.82, .72, .6, .5, .45]
col = ['k', 'b', 'm', 'g', 'r']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(12, 4))

axs[0].set_title('Problem: hlines in foreround')
for d, c in zip(data, col):
    axs[0].plot([0, d], c, lw=10)
for d in data:
    axs[0].axhline(d, lw=5)

axs[1].set_title('Solution 1: zorder=0 for hlines')
for d, c in zip(data, col):
    axs[1].plot([0, d], c, lw=10)
for d in data:
    axs[1].axhline(d, lw=5, zorder=0)

axs[2].set_title('Solution 2: plot hlines first')
for d in data:
    axs[2].axhline(d, lw=5)
for d, c in zip(data, col):
    axs[2].plot([0, d], c, lw=10)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful